# Does eclipse check validity of plugin websites?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

It might sound odd to ask this, but I just want to know is it safe to install any plugin (related to java coding) available via "Eclipse market place"/ "Install new software" ?

Thanks.

Comment: How would Eclipse do that? Eclipse don't have the resources of companies like Apple or Google to check the validity of every app/plugin.

Comment: It's not vetted in the same way that Apple's App Store handles its content, no.